# How to drop float feature where % NANs is higher than a certain number?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to drop a feature which if float and a number of missing values is higher than certain number.

I've tried:

```
# Define threshold to 1/6
threshold = 0.1667

# Drop float > threshold 
for f in data: 
if data[f].dtype==float & data[f].isnull().sum() / data.shape[0] > threshold: del data[f]
```

..which raises an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'type' and
>   'numpy.float64'

Help would be aprreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for only floats columns, check missing values and get `mean` - `sum/count` and add another non floats columns by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html), last filter by `inverse` condition `>` to `<=` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
np.random.seed(2019)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan,1], p=(0.2,0.8),size=(10,10))).assign(A='a')
print (df)
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  A
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
1  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  a
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  a
4  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  a
5  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
6  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
7  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
8  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
9  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  a

threshold = 0.1667
df1 = df.select_dtypes(float).isnull().mean().reindex(df.columns, fill_value=False)
df = df.loc[:, df1 <= threshold]
print (df)
     0    2    3    4    5    8    9  A
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
1  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  a
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  a
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
5  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
6  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
7  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
8  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
9  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  a
```

Comment: The syntax pass but the NANs seems intacted.

Comment: @StanislavJirak - Added sample data, solution working nice.